# Convert CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.Authenticode.FindSuitableCertificate to C#

Tags: certificate, signing, authenticode, codefluent

I'm trying to convert `Dim certificate As X509Certificate2 = CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.Authenticode.FindSuitableCertificate()` from VB.Net to C# and I know that it's `X509Certificate2 AuthenticodeCert = CodeFluent.Runtime.Utilities.Authenticode.FindSuitableCertificate();`

The problem is that in C# it produces a ArgumentNullException, but works in VB.Net.

```
    X509Certificate2 AuthenticodeCert = Authenticode.FindSuitableCertificate(); // Problem
            // Check if there is a  Certificate in the Certificate Store that can signs code.
            if (Authenticode.CanSignCode(AuthenticodeCert) == true) // Problem ArgumentNullException
            {// Bla, Bla}
```

Any help would be Appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
X509Certificate2 AuthenticodeCert = new X509Certificate2("PFX_Private_Key", "Password");
```

The only problem is if it returns null then I hit an error. The only remedying it seems for that was to Try Catch. Anyone know a better way to code for the null value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CodeFluent.Runtime library is a .Net framework library independant of the calling language. It is itself implemented in C# .

So I suspect your issue is not related to the language you use, but the local machine certificate stores or the executing user that are different.

The default **FindSuitableCertificate** looks into the **My** certificate store for **Current User**.
There is another more advanced signature you can use if the signing certificate installed on the machine is installed somewhere else instead :

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Finds a suitable certificate for authenticode signing.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="storeName">The store name.</param>
    /// <param name="storeLocation">The store location.</param>
    /// <param name="thumbPrint">The optional thumbprint. May be null.</param>
    /// <returns>A certificate instance or null if not found.</returns>
    public static X509Certificate2 FindSuitableCertificate(StoreName storeName, StoreLocation storeLocation, string thumbPrint)
```